# How to convert a RGB poster to CMYK with Pantone Colours as reference? (Result must be EXACTLY like RGB)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, pantone

My file is in RGB, but I need to print it with CMYK.

I have tried several printers but they just use my RGB files and print directly, and the result is so bad and dull.

My previous printer managed to do it after I gave them the Pantone colours for the logo, and the result has the same vibrancy as what you see on screen(same as the RGB file), but they are no more around.

How do I adjust it on my own using Photoshop CS6 with the pantone colours as reference?

Please advise, anybody? HELP~!

Comment: Points for the most circular, illogical, question :) RGB.. no.. CMYK.. no.... Pantone.. to be printed CMYK.. but wait.. it must look like RGB.

Comment: I believe your are confusing Pantone spot colors with CMYK printing. They are very different things.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot print RGB. Ink is CYMK.

What *may* have happened is that your previous printer printed your logo as spot colors rather than converting the RGB to CMYK. So instead of using four plates to combine into process colors, they used pre-mixed ink matched to your PANTONE colors and printed however many plates/colors you had. This is just a guess.

The solution is to stop designing print jobs in RGB, because you (and the client) will always be disappointed. Design in the space which your final product will be in so everyone's expectations are managed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're working within a common RGB color space (sRGB and AdobeRGB being the most common), any good print shop will start by converting from that RGB space to their own, custom-built CMYK profile specific to their print process.

You should be able to provide them the digital file and a hard-copy showing the results you're looking for, and they should be able to deliver something extremely close to that, barring certain factors that can limit color output, such as paper color and inkset.

Most RGB color spaces have some colors that exceed the gamut of any CMYK printer, so best-guess attempts are made by the converting software to approximate the out-of-gamut colors' appearance.

For the most control, you'll want to do that RGB-to-CMYK conversion yourself, which will require you getting the custom CMYK profile from your print shop.  Then you can manipulate the converted image to your heart's desire before submitting for print.

If you find that too many of your RGB file's colors are out of the CMYK gamut, and don't like the initial conversion results, you may want to give a little-known RGB color space a try.  It's called [PhotoGamutRGB](http://www.photogamut.org/E_ICC_profile.html). It's gamut contains only colors that can be reproduced on printers of all kinds.  So it's a better starting-point for RGB-to-CMYK for print, IMO.

Answer (score -4):

Sorry, Jes.

Designers that work with terrible printers will tell you it can't be done. And they'll tell you about a million arbitrary rules of all manner of nonsense. None of it matters. It's old thinking, at it's best. Which is worse than anything you'll ever think.

Think of a printer like a race driver thinks of his chief engineer. You don't need to understand how print technology works or how cars suspension technologies and tunings impact balance. But you do need a printer that understands your goals and feedback to get the performance you desire.

It can be done. You can find another pinter that gets what you're up to. Even when your use of RGB strays far outside the realms of CMYK a truly great printer will find ways of getting near your vision.

And clearly you had a printer who understood your images and intentions and were within the capacity of your printer's abilities. Those guys are worth their weight in gold.

This is extremely annoying, but best described thus:

The screen is mightier than the printed page. Mainly because the imaginations of printers and the rules they've come up with for mass production are restrictive. Terribly so, mostly.  But some printers realise this and work to find what a designer wants to do, or even make the previously impossible into reality. These guys will even go so far as suggesting ways you can push their technological capabilities and that of their tools and trade, for the joy of doing it. They want an experimental and exploratory designer as much as you want a great printer.

I suggest you're best served by going to every printer in your access/range with a demonstration of the prior effort (physical and digital file) and start trying to find the next printer that's going to be your partner.

This will be the most valuable experience you'll ever have in printed design because you'll eventually find the one that is worth working with, and realise just how rare and wonderful he is. So you'll treat him with the respect he deserves and shower him in gifts each time he secures another contract for you with great output, with that magical vibrancy nobody else can do.

Cause here's the real key to this magical symbiotic relationship that can exist between an experimental and exploratory designer and a crafty, technically brilliant and caring printer... you can make stuff that nobody else can in your area. He's the only one of him, and you're likely the only one of you. And that point of difference in quality and vibrancy, punch and impact in your printed designs will make you stand out like nothing else can.

Good luck, Jes.

Comment: I want to bump this up so bad, but I know I shouldn't :)

Comment: This is either some epic trolling, or a horribly misguided rant of someone who does not know what they are talking about. The brilliance is in the fact that I am unable to tell which one it is...

Comment: I worked at a printers for 12 months whilst a design student. I can say with certainty that we would have put strychnine in this guys tea. Print companies have standards and can be set up for unusual stocks / prestige work but it's a factory and time costs everyone money.  What they want is a high quality, preflighted file (with fonts converted to paths) and a stock / finish indication from a professional who knows how to set up for print, NOT to go on an endless Alice Through The Looking Glass expedition in support of a naive creative's wet dream and ambition.  How do these people survive?

Comment: They find GREAT printers, with patience, understanding and a compassion for creatives. You're not one of them. Your type were mentioned. You're normal. These relationships are not normal. I mentioned that it's quite hard to find someone in the printing industry sympathetic to the creative's objectives when suffering from a naivety about print's limitations and the differences from the screen. If you're into production runs at the greatest efficiency, and least effort for the printer, then you're simply not this wonderful, caring printer... you're normal. Nothing wrong with that. @Applefanboy

Comment: Friend I wish you well on your journey. I don't know what your personal circumstances are but I have a mortgage and 2 children to provide for so I don't live on a cloud dreaming or try to out do Carson or Mariscal. And I don't consider myself normal or average. I've been a successful 'creative' designer for 20+ years working internationally and managing to consistently challenge myself whilst hitting deadlines and budget. I have been with one of my printers since college and I teach@  Uni to Masters level. There is a place and time for experimentation - its on your clock, not the contractors.

Comment: @Applefanboy money doesn't make the world go round. It only makes jets go round the world.

Comment: A reduced perspective (time as money) and assuming all operate in a limited reality isn't helpful to someone seeking a printer wise in the twin mediums (digital & print) and willing to help a purely digital creative overcome their limitations. For those valuing creativity (and those compassionate, considerate and caring about its utilisation, realisation and distribution) the trials and tribulations of inspiration, conception and articulation are worth it, so they may communicate: they value the message over the medium. Printers willing to mentor/assist a designer limited to RGB exist!

Comment: I agree -- epic trolling or something close. Asking a printer to caress an ignorant, designer to ensure that the product achieves his creative vision is unrealistic and arrogant. Do you go to a restaurant and tell the chef you are dreaming about a dish that he should prepare for you, or else he sucks at his job? Printers are in business (as are designers, supposedly). One of your jobs as a designer is to learn and understand the REALITIES of print production. Otherwise, open a studio in a barn, do your own lithography or silk screening by hand, and enjoy your pure artistic vision.

Comment: Oh dear. Quote "money doesn't make the world go round. It only makes jets go round the world." Tell that to the working graphic designer who cannot pay his mortgage because he's just been laid off. Or my pal John who cannot work in a design office because of his diabetes and poor health. He is still operating at home as a designer, and having to be ultra careful on every job, pro that he is. You really have no idea. Have a nice day. Obama OUT.